# How to customize wx.ProgressDialog?

Tags: python, wxpython, progress-bar

Is it possible to customize ProgressDialog in wxPython?
For instance, I would like to make the progressbar slimmer, and the window size wider.

`SetSize()` method doesn't appear to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wx.ProgressDialog` isn't customizable its just a wrapper around the native `ProgressDialog`, the the easiest solution would be to roll your own by extending the `wx.Dialog` class and using a `wx.Gauge`

Comment: There's also a pure python version of the ProgressDialog called PyProgress. It's in wx.lib.agw. If it doesn't do what you'd like, you can hack it.